# Checkbox status issue

Tags: android, checkbox

How we can know whether the check box is checked or unchecked using java code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
boolean checkBox.isChecked()
```

returns true if your 'checkBox' is checked, returns false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If your checkbox is part of a preference menu, you can do:

```
boolean checked;
checked = preferences.getBoolean("checkBoxName", true);
```

Where "preferences" is your [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) object.

See [this page](http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences) for further reference on how to implement a preference menu.